# How to modify a list value in a nested custom datatype?

Tags: list, haskell, nested

Say I've made a new data type as follows:

```
data Typex = Typex {
   level       :: Int,
   coordinate  :: (Int, Int),
   connections :: [(Int,(Int,Int),Double)]  -- edited to be a tuple
   } deriving Show
```

I want to modify the connections from an upper level where I use  `[[TypeX]]`. Do I need nested loops, fmap and a functor instance for my custom type or what would you suggest?

Comment: Haskell doesn't have loops. Your type isn't parametrically polymorphic, so that rules out a `Functor` instance, too. That only leaves `fmap`, or just `map`.

Comment: Yes, connections is supposed to be a list of 3-tuples. Edited that to the original question

Comment: @MarkSeemann Haskell has (nested) loops through hand-coded recursion with (mutually recursive) worker function(s). you probably meant dedicated loop constructs, but even then, list comprehensions with *n* successive generators express *n*-levels-deep nested loops. :)

Comment: @MarkSeemann Why is `fmap` an option if there's no `Functor` instance? I would've though I'd need the instance to use it.

Comment: You can use `fmap` (or `map`) on the (list of) list.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Yes that's what I understood from your first message. What I didn't understand is why it's possible.

Comment: List is a `Functor` instance: [`Functor []`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Functor.html).

Comment: Got it . Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, describe how you want to modify a single connection. Give it a name:

```
modConnection (i, (j, k), d) = (i + 42, (j*5, k), d)
```

To update a whole list of connections, use `map`:

```
modConnections cons = map modConnection cons
```

To update a field in the record, use the Haskell record update syntax:

```
modTypeX :: TypeX -> TypeX
modTypeX tx = tx { connections = modConnections (connections tx) }
```

To update a whole list of these records, use `map` again:

```
modTypeXList txs = map modTypeX txs
```

And finally, to update a whole list of these lists, use `map` once again:

```
modTypeXListList txs = map modTypeXList txs
```

Of course, if you don't want to give a name to every intermediate function, you don't have to, you can do everything inline:

```
modTypeXListList = map . map $ \tx -> tx { connections = map modConnection (connections tx) }
```

Comment: This looks like something I could manage. Lens approach would probably work as well but I'd rather use something simpler like this if possible. 

The end goal is to have a [[Typex]] -> [[Typex]] function which produces lots of those connection 3-tuples in each TypeX but all Int values in them depend on the structure of [[Typex]] given to the function, while keeping the rest of the values unchanged.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want [lenses](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens).

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell   #-}

import Control.Lens

data Typex = Typex
  { _level       :: Int
  , _coordinate  :: (Int, Int)
  , _connections :: [(Int,(Int,Int),Double)]
  } deriving Show
makeLenses ''Typex

main :: IO ()
main = print $ [[Typex 0 (0,0) []]
               ,[Typex 1 (1,1) [], Typex 1 (2,2) []]
               ,[]]
             & ix 1 . ix 0 . connections
                 %~ ((9,(9,9),pi):)
```

In this example, the the nested list is *indexed* (`ix`) into the head of the middle element, in that `Typex` value focused on the `connections` field, and there the element `(9,(9,9),pi)` prepended. Result:

```
[[Typex {_level = 0, _coordinate = (0,0), _connections = []}],[Typex {_level = 1, _coordinate = (1,1), _connections = [(9,(9,9),3.141592653589793)]},Typex {_level = 1, _coordinate = (2,2), _connections = []}],[]]
```

Comment: Yes it seems just plain list comprehensions won't cut it. Could you (or anyone else) give an example or hint how I could use lenses to achieve those references to indices I mention in the question? I suppose I'll have to use something from Control.Lens.Indexed but that's about it.

Comment: It's seems you've asked a completely separate question there. Don't use “edit question” to ask new questions! I suggest you roll back that change and actually post as a new question instead.

Comment: Sure. That was probably a bit too much to add in the same question. Made a new one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60545053/how-to-modify-fields-of-a-nested-custom-data-type-with-lenses-when-modification