# How to modify fields of a nested custom data type with lenses, when modifications depend on indices

Tags: haskell, nested, indices, haskell-lens, custom-data-type

Considering the following :

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell   #-}

import Control.Lens

data Typex = Typex 
    { _level       :: Int
    , _coordinate  :: (Int, Int)
    , _connections :: [(Int,(Int,Int))]
    } deriving Show
makeLenses ''Typex

initTypexLevel :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [Typex] 
initTypexLevel a b c = [ Typex a (x, y) [(0,(0,0))]
                       | x <- [0..b], y <- [0..c]
                       ]

buildNestedTypexs :: [(Int, Int)] -> [[Typex]]
buildNestedTypexs pts
     = setConnections [ initTypexLevel i y y
                      | (i,(_,y)) <- zip [0..] pts
                      ]

setConnections :: [[Typex]] -> [[Typex]]
setConnections = ?
```

How can I uses lenses to modify the `connections` in all`Typex`s with a function of type `[[Typex]] -> [[Typex]]` in such a way that in each `Typex`

```
connections = [(level of Typex being modified +1, (x, y))] where
x,y = 0..(length of next [Typex] in [[Typex]])/2
```

X and y both need to go through that length of the next [Typex]. The final [Typex] should be left unchanged if possible. So all the connections of each Typex in the same [Typex] are the same.

Output for `setConnections $ buildNestedTypexs [(0,1),(1,1)]` should be:

```
[ [ Typex { _level = 0
          , _coordinate = (0,0)
          , _connections = [(1,(0,0)), (1,(0,1)), (1,(1,0)), (1,(1,1))] }
  , Typex { _level = 0
          , _coordinate = (0,1)
          , _connections = [(1,(0,0)), (1,(0,1)), (1,(1,0)), (1,(1,1))] }
  , Typex { _level = 0
          , _coordinate = (1,0)
          , _connections = [(1,(0,0)), (1,(0,1)), (1,(1,0)), (1,(1,1))] }
  , Typex { _level = 0
          , _coordinate = (1,1)
          , _connections = [(1,(0,0)), (1,(0,1)), (1,(1,0)), (1,(1,1))] }
  ]
 ,[ Typex { _level = 1
          , _coordinate = (0,0)
          , _connections = [(0,(0,0))] }
  , Typex { _level = 1
          , _coordinate = (0,1)
          , _connections = [(0,(0,0))] }
  , Typex { _level = 1
          , _coordinate = (1,0)
          , _connections = [(0,(0,0))] }
  , Typex { _level = 1
          , _coordinate = (1,1)
          , _connections = [(0,(0,0))] }
  ]]
```

I suppose I'll need to `import Control.Lens.Indexed` but that's about it so all help is appreciated.

Comment: A concrete example would be useful to see what exactly the question is.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I added more explanation and an expected result. In it the connections of `Typex`s with level 1 were left unchanged, because they're part of the last [Typex] given as an argument.

Comment: Ok, I guess it's technically clear now, but... can't you simplify/generalise the question a bit? This still seems quite involved with domain-specific details that aren't really relevant to the core of what you're asking.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks for making that a bit more readable. I removed the Double part from connections because it was irrelevant considering the problem. Other than that I don't really know how to make this more general without adding a bunch of variables which would probably make it even more difficult to understand.

Comment: Can we also get rid of the `c` parameter and avoid nested tuples altogether?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Not really because I'll need that nested tuple in the final solution anyway. Nevertheless, a working solution even without it is still useful.

Comment: I'm confused about the description of the desired transformation versus the example given.  Since the second `[Typex]` has length 4, shouldn't the connections in the first `[Typex]` be set to `[(1,(x,y)) | x <- [0..4], y <- [0..4]]`?  Or is "length" supposed to be "index"?

Comment: @K.A.Buhr True, there was a mistake in the explanation of desired transformation but it should be right now. The idea is that every `Typex` should be connected to every `Typex` in the next `[Typex]` of `[[Typex]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

setConnections :: [[Typex]] -> [[Typex]]
setConnections (x:rest@(y:_)) = map (connect y) x : setConnections rest
  where connect :: [Typex] -> Typex -> Typex
        connect txs tx
          = tx & connections .~ (map ((tx ^. level) + 1,) $ txs ^.. traverse.coordinate)
setConnections lst = lst
```

This isn't a pure lens solution, but I find that as a general rule when working with lenses, it's not always a good idea to get the lenses to do *everything*.  It just makes things difficult to write and hard to understand.

Here, I've used "plain Haskell" in a lot of places:  to pattern matching with a manual recursion to process pairs `x`,`y` of consecutive `[Typex]`s and I've used `map` to `connect` each `Typex` in the first `x :: [Typex]` with the second `y :: [Typex]`.  I've also used `map` to add the new level to the coordinate list to generate the new `connections` value.

The only lens expressions used here are:

- `tx & connections .~ (...)` which replaces the `connections` field of `tx :: Typex` with a new value
- `tx ^. level` which fetches the level of the current `tx :: Typex`
- `txs ^.. traverse.coordinate` which fetches the `coordinate` fields of all `Typex` values in the list `txs :: [Typex]` and returns them as a list `[(Int,Int)]`

In my opinion, this sort of balance between lenses and "plain Haskell" is the best way of dealing with complex transformations.

Comment: I tried that solution with different input values and it seems to work exactly as it should. Thank you.

Now I just have to figure out what it actually does in each part to modify it a bit :)

Comment: I added some explanation of which lens expressions do what, in case that helps.